# EasyPHP cannot modify hosts file

Tags: permissions, hosts, virtual-host, easyphp

I am using the Virtual Hosts Manager module to add a virtual host so I can access my local site on the browser like so: `http://mysite.local/`. But I am getting this message:

> Unfortunately, you do not have rights to create a Virtual Host. You must have write permissions on the file: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

[image: Unfortunately, you do not have rights to create a Virtual Host. You must have write permissions on the file: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts]

I have

1. Given the `hosts` full access to my user, `System` and even `Everyone`
2. Run EasyPHP executable as Admin

But I still keep getting this message. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly giving `Users (ComputerName\Users)` write permissions fixed this issue!

[image: Write permissions for Users (ComputerName\Users)]

Comment: I wouldn't do this. This gives any program on your computer permissions to modify your hosts file and redirect your internet traffic.